# Multi-Tenant SAML: How can I identify local account from Response element?

Tags: security, saml

I am adding SAML Service Provider support to an existing multi-tenant SaaS application.

In a Idp-initiated workflow, assuming I've previously loaded the Idp metadata XML file, what data can I look for in the `samlp:Response` to match an assertion to a local account?

Is it safe to match the `saml:Issuer` in the response against the `entityID` in the metadata? Could `saml:Issuer` not be unique across different Idp accounts and thus are not distinct enough?

What about using `Audience` instead?

Or is it safest to provide our own attribute for the Idp to populate?

Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

`Audience` is your service. The `Issuer` is a good candidate because it identifies the source of authentication (e.g. your customer's IdP).

Comment: In the case of ADFS, is it possible that 2 Relying Parties configured in the same organization can both use the same issuer ID?

Comment: If you have an intermmediary ADFS (as a "Federation Provider"), you can always add an additional claim (e.g. Tenant) that represents the downstream IdP. makes sense?